# Colleague got promoted instead of me but quit shortly after!

Tags: promotion

I have been working in a medium-size ad agency for 5 years.  I started out as a designer but after about a year, I started to talk to my manager about possibly being promoted to Art Director since I have 15 years of experience in the industry and have prior experience as an AD. My manager said it could absolutely be a possibility and that we should see how I’m going in the performance review 6 months down the line.

However, by that time I had gotten a new boss. I had to start over and got the same response, let’s see how it’s going for the next 6 months. I worked hard and always did more than what was expected of me but when 6 months had passed, I was told that no promotions were possible at the time.

I worked for another year, trying my best to show that I was fit for a higher position but then I got a new boss again. We had a chat and I told him of my ambitions, he seemed to really see my value in the company and promised that he’d get me promoted as soon as possible.

A couple of weeks ago they called me into a meeting to let me know that they’d given the promotion to one of my colleagues (7 years my junior and with roughly half of my industry experience). I was gutted, I started to question if this industry is really for me, or if upper management had some problems with me personally.

And then came the twist. A few days after his promotion my colleague announced he was leaving for a similar position in another company. A friend in another department told me that they are considering giving the position to me now.

Several people in my team quit in the last couple of years and we are in a position where everyone is pretty much key at the moment. So if I too would leave now, they would be left with just one employee that could somewhat do what we did.

I don’t know what to do, I feel like they are not treating me very well, I have been very loyal and hard-working. Should I accept the promotion if they give it to me and then just apply for a job somewhere else with the new title? (like my colleague did) or what would you do?

Comment: What do you gain when you don't take the promotion if they really give the promotion to you ?

Comment: what stopped you to quit and search outside? why did you waste somuch time?

Comment: *"I don’t know what to do..."* We can't tell you what choice to make. If you [edit] your post to tell us what you want to happen we can give you answers about how to achieve that.

Comment: I am not sure if me feeling humiliated is just silly and I should just take the promotion and smile if it's offered to me. The whole thing has made me lose a lot of confidence. I know I stayed there to long, but I liked my colleagues and the projects I got to work on.

I know no one can tell me what to do, but I am asking what you would have done in my position.

Comment: There are a lot of people that think they deserve promotion, but the company disagees. They have to balance a range of things, and sometimes the best option isn't to take maybe the most experienced, but the person most suitable for the rule.

Comment: Flag for me is "why did your colleague accept and then leave so quickly"? Either they were leaving anyway so why take the promotion, or they found out something about the post and found a new job quickly... Either way I would not be looking to accept that promotion.

Answer (score 10):

I see no reason to not at least take the promotion if it was offered to you. I don't think you stand to lose anything by taking the promotion. If you really feel like they don't treat you well, you might consider looking for a new job, but that's no reason to not take the promotion in my opinion. If anything it might make your job search easier.

But for now I think you should just wait and see what they do. Maybe they'll offer you the promotion with such a great raise and benefits package you don't even want to leave anymore. And maybe they won't and you will feel insulted and not treated well. Only time will tell on that.

Answer (score 6):

> A couple of weeks ago they called me into a meeting to let me know that they’d given the promotion to one of my colleagues (7 years my junior and with roughly half of my industry experience).

That is is your assessment: The company does not consider you to be a top performer or of high value. Not bad enough to fire but also not good enough to promote or grow. It doesn't matter what they say, you have to look at what they actually do. This assessment is fairly normal and happens to a lot of people.

> I was gutted, I started to question if this industry is really for me, or if upper management had some problems with me personally.

Stop being emotional and start to think rationally. There is a perfectly good explanation for this treatment.

> A friend in another department told me that they are considering giving the position to me now.

Don't put too much stake in rumors and what other people say. Start to take this seriously only if you have credible communication from your direct management or an actual offer in hand.

> So if I too would leave now, they would be left with just one employee that could somewhat do what we did.

Not your problem.

> I feel like they are not treating me very well,

You are being treated the same as many other people: based on your perceived value to the company.

> I have been very loyal and hard-working.

That's nice, but only one part of being a good performer: there is also technical skill, communication, organizational awareness, creativity, etc.

> I don’t know what to do

You have two basic choices here:

1. Continue "as is" and make your peace with the situation. If a promotion actually comes along, treat is an unexpected bonus.
2. Look for a new job with better growth opportunity.

Answer (score 3):

> And then came the twist. A few days after his promotion my colleague
> announced he was leaving for a similar position in another company. A
> friend in another department told me that they are considering giving
> the position to me now.

Note you have a rumor of a promotion. In the past you had vague promises from managers, which only served to keep you with the company.

> Several people in my team quit in the last couple of years and we are
> in a position where everyone is pretty much key at the moment. So if I
> too would leave now, they would be left with just one employee that
> could somewhat do what we did.

When deciding to switch companies this should never be your concern. If they are understaffed, they need to rectify the situation.

But if they offer your the promotion, then the under staffing is a big concern. You will either be helping them find replacements or you will be expected to do the Art Director job with a reduced staff. You will have to decide, based on your knowledge of the company, which path they are expected to follow.

> Should I accept the promotion if they give it to me and then just
> apply for a job somewhere else with the new title? (like my colleague
> did) or what would you do?

If they were to offer you the promotion today, and you don't already have an offer from another company, deciding to accept the promotion (and raise) puts extra money in your pocket. It also allows you to see if you can do the job, and gives you a new perspective on your current company.  Rejecting the promotion, after all the waiting you did, could set off alarm bells with your current manager. They could realize you are on your way out the door.

Having a new title for only a month or two doesn't lock in the title if you go to another company. They would see on the CV/Resume that you only had the position for a short time. They could also realize this in the interview process. They could discount this short term promotion as not important when evaluating you for a job. Remember you said you have prior experience as an AD, and it hasn't resulted in a promotion despite many years of trying.

If you are tired of waiting, then start looking. If you aren't tired of waiting, then wait and see what happens.